# Spring Integration Get HTTP Outbound Gateway Response

Tags: gateway, spring-integration, transformer-model, payload

I need to POST a REST service call and get the data it returns (all of this is with JSON).  I have an outbound-gateway with its reply-channel as a chain, and the chain has one transformer.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
    url="#{appProperties['rootUrl']}#{appProperties['myMethod']}"
    request-channel="myRequestChannel" reply-channel="myResponseChannel" >
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="myResponseChannel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="myResponseChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="genericResponseTransformer"/>
</int:chain>
```

However when I debug through the transformer, the payload I get back is just an HttpStatus object.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not specify `expected-response-type` in your gateway, the default behavior is that the response message contains only status code (expected-response-type is null). Try setting `expected-response-type="java.lang.String"`:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
  url="#{appProperties['rootUrl']}"
  http-method="#{appProperties['myMethod']}"
  expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
  request-channel="myRequestChannel" reply-channel="myResponseChannel" />
```